# kill-buffer with y-or-n-p instead of yes-or-no-p

Tags: kill-buffer

**Q**:  How can I use `y-or-n-p` -- *instead of* `yes-or-no-p` -- when calling `kill-buffer` for just the duration of a particular function?

In other words, I want the behavior of `(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)` but only for the duration of a particular function without any lasting effect.

**CAVEAT**:  I would like to please avoid using `(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)` at the outset and `(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'yes-or-no-p)` at the tail end of the function, just in case I decide to exit out of the function with a `'quit` signal such as `C-g`, in which case the effect would become long-lasting rather than merely temporary.

Here is a test snippet to start with:

```lisp
(let* (
    (filename "/private/tmp/foofile")
    (buf (get-buffer-create "*foo*")))
  (with-current-buffer buf
    (write-file filename)
    (insert "Every good boy deserves fudge."))
  (kill-buffer buf)
  (delete-file filename))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advice `kill-buffer`:

```el
(defun yes-or-no-p->-y-or-n-p (orig-fun &rest r)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'yes-or-no-p) #'y-or-n-p))
    (apply orig-fun r)))

(advice-add 'kill-buffer :around #'yes-or-no-p->-y-or-n-p)
```

or advice `yes-or-no-p`

```el
(defun yes-or-no-p@maybe-just-y-or-n-p (orig-fun prompt)
  (funcall
   (if (eq this-command 'kill-buffer)
       #'y-or-n-p
     #'yes-or-no-p)
   prompt))

(advice-add 'yes-or-no-p :around #'yes-or-no-p@maybe-just-y-or-n-p)
```

Comment: I modified your example to make a type of let-bound version for just the duration of the function -- thank you very much -- greatly appreciated:  `(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'yes-or-no-p) #'y-or-n-p)) (let* ((filename "/private/tmp/foofile") (buf (get-buffer-create "*foo*"))) (with-current-buffer buf (write-file filename) (insert "Every good boy deserves fudge.")) (kill-buffer buf) (delete-file filename)))`

Answer (score 3):

> just in case I decide to exit out of the function with a 'quit signal such as C-g, in which case the effect would become long-lasting rather than merely temporary.

This can be solved with `unwind-protect`. The following function always restores `yes-or-no-p`'s definition at the end even if you quit in the middle of it:

```el
(defun my/kill-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((yes-or-no-def (symbol-function 'yes-or-no-p)))
    (unwind-protect
        (progn
          (fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)
          (call-interactively #'kill-buffer))
      (fset 'yes-or-no-p yes-or-no-def))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative method of handling the issue -- greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to handle this is to use `cl-letf`, like so:

```el
(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'yes-or-no-p) #'y-or-n-p))
  (let* ((filename "~/private/tmp/foofile")
         (buf (get-buffer-create "*foo*")))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (write-file filename)
      (insert "Every good boy deserves fudge."))
    (kill-buffer buf)
    (delete-file filename)))
```

This is in principle similar to whacka's answer, but avoids requiring an explicit `unwind-protect`.

Comment: Your answer is the best (in my opinion), and I independently came up with the same solution once I understood how the answer by xuchunyang worked in conjunction with advice.  Since I accepted the answer by xuchunyang at the outset, and since it contained the ingredients that immediately helped me resolve the issue, I don't feel good taking away the check-mark.  However, please definitely leave your formal answer here as it is the best answer (in my opinion) and will help other people in the future when they find this thread with Google and what not  Thank you.