# What is the best way to modify an existing function from a package?

Tags: ess

There is a function in ESS called **ess-sas-goto-log** (https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/master/lisp/ess-sas-a.el#L705) that will open a log file and search forward using re-search-forward. I would like to make a version that searches backwards. What would be the best way to go about this?

I know I can simply replace search-forward with search-backward but I would like to do it the proper way.

Thanks!

Comment: It is a matter of taste / personal preference.  I am the only person I know who likes to modify the source code directly and take complete control.  Most everyone else in the world goes out of his/her way to try and figure out how to use `advice` if at all possible, and everyone (but me) seems to love/up-vote that approach.  A small handful of people post answers that use `(require 'name-of-library)` followed by the new revised function with **the same name** so that the old function gets redefined.  And there are a small minority of people who might create a new function and use `defalias`.

Comment: And, see also this related thread that redefines a function on a temporary basis using `cl-letf`:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22571/2287  I have a comment underneath the answer that demonstrates how I applied it to my particular use-case.  I don't see a lot of answers using that, perhaps because it is a little advanced -- but it sure is nifty (in my opinion).  On another note, there is a very important distinction between `search-forward` versus `re-search-forward` and `search-backward` versus `re-search-backward`. One uses a literal string, whereas the other searches by a regexp.

Comment: Too broad. Specify what you mean by "*best*". Just what are you looking for?

Comment: Yes, I realize that "best" isn't the best word. I am looking for what were accepted conventions of re-purposing an existing function such that it avoids breaking and headaches.

lawlist pretty much answer the questions I had. Many thanks!